# BeautifulSoup: extract text from anchor tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, scraper

I want to extract:

- text from following src of the `image` tag and
- text of the anchor tag which is inside the `div` class data

I successfully manage to extract the img src, but am having trouble extracting the text from the anchor tag.

```
<a class="title" href="http://www.amazon.com/Nikon-COOLPIX-Digital-Camera-NIKKOR/dp/B0073HSK0K/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1343628292&amp;sr=1-1&amp;keywords=digital+camera">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a>
```

Here is the link for the entire [HTML page](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n:172282,k:digital%20camera&keywords=digital%20camera&ie=UTF8&qid=1343600585).

Here is my code:

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'image'}):
    print "\n"
    for data in div.findNextSibling('div', attrs={'class':'data'}):
        for a in data.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'title'}):
            print a.text
    for img in div.findAll('img'):
        print img['src']
```

What I am trying to do is **extract the image src (link) and the title inside the `div class=data`**, so for example:

```
 <a class="title" href="http://www.amazon.com/Nikon-COOLPIX-Digital-Camera-NIKKOR/dp/B0073HSK0K/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1343628292&amp;sr=1-1&amp;keywords=digital+camera">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a>
```

should extract:

> `Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)`

Comment: I am looking for the text not text of href

Comment: did you mean like this print div.find('a').string then I get None

Comment: Posted an answer that does what you want... (I think) - but would personally go for the lxml.html parser route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the above answers really help me to construct my answer, because of this I voted for all the answers that other users put it out: But I finally put together my own answer to exact problem I was dealing with:

As question clearly defined I had to access some of the siblings and its children in a dom structure: This solution will iterate over the images in the dom structure and construct image name using product title and save the image to the local directory.

```
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def getImages(url):
    #Download the images
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text
    soup = bs(html)
    output_folder = '~/amazon'
    #extracting the images that in div(s)
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'image'}):
        modified_file_name = None
        try:
            #getting the data div using findNext
            nextDiv =  div.findNext('div', attrs={'class':'data'})
            #use findNext again on previous object to get to the anchor tag
            fileName = nextDiv.findNext('a').text
            modified_file_name = fileName.replace(' ','-') + '.jpg'
        except TypeError:
            print 'skip'
        imageUrl = div.find('img')['src']
        outputPath = os.path.join(output_folder, modified_file_name)
        urlretrieve(imageUrl, outputPath)

if __name__=='__main__':
    url = r'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Adigital+camera&keywords=digital+camera&ie=UTF8&qid=1343600585'
    getImages(url)
```

Answer (score 86):

This will help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class="image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/eg1">Content1<img  
        src="http://image.example.com/img1.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/eg2">Content2<img  
        src="http://image.example.com/img2.jpg" /> </a>
        </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'image'}):
    print(div.find('a')['href'])
    print(div.find('a').contents[0])
    print(div.find('img')['src'])
```

If you are looking into Amazon products then you should be using the official API. There is at least [one Python package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/) that will ease your scraping issues and keep your activity within the terms of use.

Comment: I am actually looking for the text example: <a class="title" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073HSK0K">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a> in this I want the Nikon COOLPIX... if I used div.find('a')['href'] that only gives the href not the text.

Comment: @gauden: [python-amazon-product-api](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/) is only available for Python 2.x. Do you or anyone have a better package recommendation?

Comment: @smci I haven’t used this for a long while. The Amazon [Product Advertising API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AnatomyOfaRESTRequest.html) has a REST interface that seems easy enough to interact with using a library like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score 34):

In my case, it worked like that:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

url="http://blabla.com"

soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url))
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print link.string
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is close, but it should be updated to convert link.string from a NavigableString to a normal string.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest going the lxml route and using xpath.

```
from lxml import etree
# data is the variable containing the html
data = etree.HTML(data)
anchor = data.xpath('//a[@class="title"]/text()')
```

Comment: I am getting following error: 'module' object has no attribute 'html' looks like etree doesn't have html object to be called upon.

Comment: Thats because I had a typo the line should be:
data = etree.HTML(data)
I have updated the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the href out of an anchor tag use `tag.get("href")` and to get the img src you use `tag.img.get("src")`.

Example, using this data:

```
data = """
            <div class="image">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/eg1">Content1<img src="http://image.example.com/img1.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/eg2">Content2<img src="http://image.example.com/img2.jpg" /> </a>
            </div>
        """
```

Get the links and texts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        return BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")

def get_links(soup):
    links = []
    for tag in soup.findAll("a", href=True):
        if img := tag.img:
            img = img.get("src")
        links.append(dict(url=tag.get("href"), text=tag.text, img=img))
    return links

# soup = get_soup('www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="html.parser")
links = get_links(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'url': 'http://www.example.com/eg1', 'text': 'Content1', 'img': 'http://image.example.com/img1.jpg'},
{'url': 'http://www.example.com/eg2', 'text': 'Content2 ', 'img': 'http://image.example.com/img2.jpg'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> txt = '<a class="title" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073HSK0K">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a> '
>>> fragment = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)
>>> fragment
<a class="title" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073HSK0K">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a> 
>>> fragment.find('a', {'class': 'title'})
<a class="title" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073HSK0K">Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)</a>
>>> fragment.find('a', {'class': 'title'}).string
u'Nikon COOLPIX L26 16.1 MP Digital Camera with 5x Zoom NIKKOR Glass Lens and 3-inch LCD (Red)'
```

Comment: so I tried like this but  print div.find('a', {'class':'title'}).string got the error:     print div.find('a', {'class':'title'}).string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: Then it's blank - try/except the block

Answer (score 1):

```
print(link_addres.contents[0])
```

It will print the context of the anchor tags

example:

```
 statement_title = statement.find('h2',class_='briefing-statement__title')
 statement_title_text = statement_title.a.contents[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'class_name'}).text
```