# Extracting link text and writing to file

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have crawler that extract links from page only if the link text include given text and I'm writing the output to html file. Its working but I would like to add whole link text next to these links like this - "Junior Java developer - https://www.jobs.cz/junior-developer/" How can I do this?

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def jobs_crawler(max_pages):
    page = 1
    file_name = 'links.html'

    while page < max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.jobs.cz/prace/praha/?field%5B%5D=200900011&field%5B%5D=200900012&field%5B%5D=200900013&page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        page += 1
        file = open(file_name,'w')

        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'search-list__main-info__title__link'}, text=re.compile('IT', re.IGNORECASE)):
            href = link.get('href') + '\n'
            file.write('<a href="' + href + '">'+ 'LINK TEXT HERE' + '</a>' + '<br />')
            print(href)
        file.close()

    print('Saved to %s' % file_name)

jobs_crawler(5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: BeautifulSoup extract text from anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716380/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-from-anchor-tag)

Comment: In case this - probably just `link.text` will do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
file.write('''<a href="{0}">{1}</a><br />'''.format(link.get('href'), link.text ))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
 href = link.get('href') + '\n'
 txt = link.get_text('href') #will give you text
```