# Extracting title from class CSS link with BeautifulSoup - HTML different formatting

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to using BeautifulSoup for web scraping and ran into the following issue: I am trying to scrape posts from a forum and I want to extract the posts' tags. Here is the HTML code of the tag class:

```
<a class="tag_css_link" href="XXXX" title="">Advanced Physics</a>
```

This format is consistent throughout the form. I tried using soup["title"] which gives me "". How can I extract "Advanced Physics"?

Comment: Do you get answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716380/beautifulsoup-extract-text-from-anchor-tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find("a", class_='tag_css_link').text
```

[image]